# Error creating partitions in Ubuntu installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, software-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside windows on my laptop, and I’ve got to the installation set up and once I’ve selected normal installation and entered my partitions it comes up with an error saying unable to create partition, I’ve tried changing them but I can’t get it working.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you open a live session and try to create the partitions with `gparted`? Then you can directly install in the newly created partitions.

Comment: *"/dev/sda Generic Flash Disk (31.0 GB)"* sounds rather like you have selected the USB installation stick instead ot the computer's internal drive

Comment: A flash drive is slower than a regular HDD. Don't use a swap partition on a flash drive. If you have enough (>4gb) RAM, it should be good enough.

Comment: Are you trying to install Ubuntu on your USB-stick, or do you want to install it along side Windows on your harddisk. The way it is setup now it will install it on a 32 GB USB-stick. If the stick is the same as the boot-device it can't make the partitions because it is in use as your boot device. Another thing is put your EFI at the beginning of the disk. If you want to use a SWAP-partition on USB ( not recommended ) place it at the end.

Comment: If you are trying to install alongside Windows there will almost certainly be an EFI partition already existing. Your Ubuntu installation should make use of that. By default Ubuntu will use a swapfile so you don’t need a swap partition either unless you particularly want to do it that way. If you don’t have much space available I wouldn’t recommend separate root and home partitions. That will only increase the likelihood of one or the other running out of space at some point in the future and causing you problems

Answer (score 0):

Experienced same problem, but i changed the usb port to primary, after that i can install ubuntu.
Try this instead